# VMware: how to set shared folders between Fedora guest and Windows host?

Tags: vmware, fedora

host: `Windows 10`
guest: `Fedora 29 server`
VMware: `Workstation 15`

I want to share `d:\workspace` of Windows with Fedora guest,
according to the docs of [open-vm-tools](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/wiki/FAQ) ,
I have installed `open-vm-tools` on Fedora via the command below:

```
yum install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

The docs of VMware Workstation [Enable a Shared Folder for a Virtual Machine](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html) does not have `open-vm-tools`,so what should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

The next step is to mount the shared folder in the Fedora guest file system:

```
vmhgfs-fuse .host:/workspace /home/myuser/workspace -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other
```

Look into the documentation for more information about using of `vmhgfs-fuse`: [Mounting Shared Folders in a Linux Guest](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html)